# Buenas, No me aparece el paquete de Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore en el administrador de paquetes NuGet en VisualStudio

Tags: entity-framework

[image: Ese paquete no me aparece en mi administrador de paquetes NuGet y eso que lo tengo instalado]

Esa paquete no me aparece en mi paquete de NuGet y eso que tengo instalado en mi Visual Studio

Comment: En la foto aparece.... o la foto es de otro computador?

Comment: Esa foto es de otro computador. En mi paquetes de NuGet no aparece entity. Y eso que lo tengo descargado

Comment: Fíjate en esta imagen, que te aparece a ti?: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1eJn.png

Comment: En el origen del paquete me aparece: Microsoft Visual Studio Offine Packages, solo esa opción

Comment: Esto es lo que me aparece: https://pasteboard.co/8yArxvQpWdbC.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer te falta el repositorio de los Nuget.

1.- Abrir la configuración, presionando el botón que está a la derecha

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.- Agregar nuevo repositorio, presionando el icono con el símbolo `+`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ```
> Nombre: nuget.org
>
> Origen: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
> ```

Comment: Gracias, esa es la solución , agregar los paquetes de Nuget . Muchas gracias nuevamente, te pasaste